# super init no longer works

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

In one of my classes I have an `-(id) init` method. The first thing that happens in that method is a call to `[super init]`

This was all fine, but I recently imported my code which was quite old into a new xcode project. I get an error on this line:

error: Automatic Reference Counting Issue: The result of a delegate init call must be immediately returned or assigned to 'self'

Why is this error occurring? is it because this is depreciated under the ARC system? or something else?

Comment: Read the error message. It already tells you very clear what's wrong and how to fix it.

Comment: @fzwo My question was also why it worked before.

Comment: Sorry to be nit-picking, but that's not what you asked. You asked why it happens now (answered by error message). (Again, I am sorry for coming across like a bean-counter, but I think it's both important and polite to try and phrase questions as clear as possible. I would not have commented if your question had read "I see the mistake and have already fixed it, but I am curious why it worked before".)

Comment: fair enough, well sorry it was unclear.

Comment: It's nothing personal, it's just that trivial questions generate some noise here, and I had mistaken yours for one. I'm glad it isn't, and you got a few good answers :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How did you do it with the old system? You're expected (on both versions) to do

```
self = [super init];

if (self) ...

return self;
```

Comment: the old way was your way, but without the `self =`. what exactly does all this do and why did it work before?

Comment: `self` is a pointer to the object that is being constructed in `init`. `[super init]` calls the constructor of the super class and `self = [super init]` assigns the variable self to point to it. If you just write `[super init]` without pointing to `self`, it might still work because somewhere up the chain you will probably have `self = [super init]` anyway... but you shouldn't assume this. I guess they deprecated this behavior with ARC.

Comment: @vakio: "because somewhere up the chain you will probably have self = [super init] anyway" This is the wrong answer. `self` is a local variable, and the assignment to a local variable in another method has no effect. The entire reason why `self = [super init];` is necessary is because `init` may return a different object than the one it was called on (or `nil`). If `init` always returned the object it was called on, then simply `[super init];` would be sufficient. The reason it still works is because 99% of the `init` methods just return the object it is called on.

Answer (score 1):

It worked before for you because LLVM is much more strict than GCC was before. GCC didn't detect the error and as @vakio pointed out in his comment, it worked because somewhere up in the chain, `self = [super init]` was present. LLVM detects this error during compile time and prevents you from compiling the incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

This worked out to me:

need assign some thing in self.

```
-(id) init {
   self = [super init];
   return self;
}
```